# When X,Y independent identically distributed random variable what about E[X|Z] where Z = X-Y

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation

$X,Y$ are iid random variable and $Z = X + Y$. To find $E[X|Z]$ I follow this procedure.

$E[Z|Z] = Z \implies E[X+Y|Z] = Z \implies E[X|Z] + E[Y|Z] = Z \implies 2E[X|Z] = Z (since  X,Y  iid E[X|Z] = E[Y|Z]) \implies E[X|Z] = Z/2$

for  $Z = X-Y $ the procedure gives $E[Z|Z] = E[X-Y|Z] = E[X|Z] - E[Y|Z] \implies E[Z|Z] = 0 \implies Z=0$ ,which obviously cannot be true.

Please let me know where the confusion is or is there anything wrong in this approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $X, Y$ are iid, we have by symmetry $E[X|X+Y]=E[Y|X+Y]$. However, $E[X|X-Y]=E[Y|X-Y]$ is not true.

In addition if you assume that the distribution is symmetric about zero, then $X, -Y$ are iid, and so
$$E[X\,|\,X-Y]\,\,=\,\,E[X\,|\,X+(-Y)]\,\,=\,\,E[(-Y)\,|\,X+(-Y)]\,\,=\,\,-E[Y\,|\,X-Y].$$

Comment: Does that mean E[X|Z] = 0?...if yes what can we say about dependency of X on Z ?

Comment: Case: Z=X-Y.  E[X|Z] need not be zero. It is just that E[X|Z] and E[Y|Z] are of opposite signs. For example, take X ~ Unif[-1,1] and Y ~ Unif[-1,1] independent of X. Then E[X|Z=1] = - E[Y|Z=1] > 0. But E[X|Z=0]=0=-E[Y|Z=0].

Answer (score 1):

In you second case, we do not have necessarly $E(X|Z)=E(Y|Z)$, because $Z=X-Y$ and the negative sign prevents e a total symmetry of the problem. However, we would expect $E(X|Y-X)=E(Y|X-Y)$